# How to getList using JPA when the first entity is the following entity after the entity with specified primary key

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

To getList form `offset` with `limit` I can use:

```
@Override
        public List<Collection> getList(int offset, int limit) {
            String SELECT_COLLECTIONS = "select collection from " + Collection.class.getName() + " collection";

            TypedQuery<Collection> query = entityManager.createQuery(SELECT_COLLECTIONS, Collection.class);
            return query.setFirstResult(offset).setMaxResults(limit).getResultList();
        }
```

Now instead of offset i have **primary key** of some entity.

**How to getList after an element which is the following element after the element with @ID?**

Example: the entites in my db have keys - **a, b, c, d, e, f**.

I need to execute **getList(b, 3)**. The result list of entites would have the keys - **c, d, e**.

Comment: setFirstResult and setMaxResults usually uses for pagination purpose. You can not do something like this. First of all you need to order your query by some columns then you can do with additional column which contain row indexes which is not suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work. For current data you could `select` entities together with `rank()`, find the value of `rank()` for specified id and then use it to query the following data (this function is vendor specific, available for example in postgres, sql server). But you're not using `order by`, what makes the result ordering not defined. After you save some data in your database, the ordering could change and the result won't be the same.

If there is a possibility you can use `id`, then you can write something like this:

```
"select collection from " + Collection.class.getName() + " collection where collection.id > :id order by collection.id";
```

And the pass a parameter `id`.

Comment: I add entities with the keys "bbb", "ccc", "aaa". getList query with offset and limit as in the question returns entities with the keys in the following order -  "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" - but i didn't sorted it. So why the result is sorted?

Comment: It's just a coincidence, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691562/does-select-distinct-imply-a-sort-of-the-results

Comment: Thank you very much